# factorial function with just lambda expression

Tags: lambda, scheme

What is the most transparent and elegant factorial function you can create, on your own, using only lambda expressions?

One of my students took a Scheme class at Berkeley and was given this extra credit problem of creating the factorial function with only lambda expressions (no define, let, or other power procedures). It took me awhile to solve, and was complicated and ugly.

I am teaching Scheme now, a couple of years later, and I realized I was going to set it as a challenge for myself, and thought others might appreciate it as well.

Comment: Are you allowed to use numbers?  Booleans (`if` or `cond`)?

Comment: Is it allowable to use `let` and/or `let*` just as an abbreviation for the `((lambda` idiom?  That would not simplify the problem any, but it would make the resulting code cleaner.

Comment: Good question. "if" and "cond" have to be allowed, otherwise there is no stopping in stopping condition. Agreed that let and let* are lambda syntactic sugar. I am shooting for an elegant tail recursive minimalist solution. You can always do both; I think I will also. Named let and letrec are certainly out.

Comment: Are you looking for a normal factorial function, with the `let`s and `define`s translated to `lambda`s?

Comment: Here's a harder challenge: do it without if, cond, or numbers. Represent the number zero as (lambda (f x) x), the number one as (lambda (f x) (f x)), the number two as (lambda (f x) (f (f x))), and in general the number 'n' as the function that consumes 'f' and 'x' and applies 'f' to 'x' 'n' times.  These are called "church numerals". In this system, you can implement 'factorial' without any if, cond, numbers, etc. Just lambda, function calls, and variable refs. Apologies if you're already familiar with this (set of) problem(s).

Comment: It's possible to write a Church numeral factorial wihtout recursion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one I did a couple of years ago had twice as many lines and was much harder to follow.

```
(lambda (n)
  ((lambda (fact) (fact fact 1 n))
   (lambda (f P n) (if (<= n 1) P (f f (* n P) (- n 1))))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's one (curried) version:

```
((lambda (x) (x x))
 (lambda (fact-gen)
   (lambda (n)
     (if (zero? n)
         1
         (* n ((fact-gen fact-gen) (sub1 n)))))))
```

Tail-recursive version:

```
(let ((fact-gen
       (lambda (fact-gen n acc)
         (if (zero? n)
             acc
             (fact-gen fact-gen (sub1 n) (* n acc))))))
  (lambda (n) (fact-gen fact-gen n 1)))
```

On Church numerals:

```
(let* ((one (lambda (s z) (s z)))
       (add1 (lambda (n) (lambda (s z) (s (n s z)))))
       (* (lambda (a b) (lambda (s z) (a (lambda (z2) (b s z2)) z))))
       (cons (lambda (a b) (lambda (f) (f a b)))))
  (lambda (n)
    ((n (lambda (p)
          (p (lambda (count acc)
               (cons (add1 count) (* count acc)))))
        (cons one one))
     (lambda (a b) b))))
```

Comment: A curried solution violates the "on your own" part of the question. For this question, I was anticipating the journey to the solution would be the most fun part.

Comment: @Tom: I think mine counts; I used what I remembered about the techniques to write the function without looking it up.

Comment: You win then. Well done. It will be interesting to what I, and others, including you, come up with for tail-recursion and further simplification

Comment: @Tom: I added the other two versions (tail-recursive and Church numeral).

Comment: Church numerals hurt my head when I first saw them in SICP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest tail-recursive version I can think of:

```
(lambda (n)
  (((lambda (!) (! !))
    (lambda (!)
      (lambda (n acc)
        (if (zero? n)
            acc
            ((! !) (sub1 n) (* n acc))))))
   n 1))
```

It's hard to get recursion in less space. The self-application has to happen somewhere, and most standalone fixpoints in a call-by-value language like Scheme have to introduce extra lambdas to avoid runaway recursion at the self-application.

Instead, my solution and Jeremiah's hide the self-application in one branch of Scheme's short-circuit `if`, giving the necessary recursion with far fewer characters.

Comment: Very nice. You did a bang up job with your code and explanation. I suspect you are right with this being minimal, but I am going to noodle on less lambdas (later). I'd bump up your answer, but can't yet

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine that I coded up before when wrapping my head around the Y-Combinator.

```
[λ (n) 
    ;; Y combinator (specialized to two arguments)
    (([λ (rec-func)
        ([λ (procedure)
           (rec-func [λ (arg1 arg2) ((procedure procedure) arg1 arg2)])]
         [λ (procedure)
           (rec-func [λ (arg1 arg2) ((procedure procedure) arg1 arg2)])])]
    ;; The factorial function (tail recursive)
     [λ (func-arg)
           [λ (n tot)
             (if (zero? n)
                 tot
                 (func-arg (- n 1) (* n tot)))]]) 
     n 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that I did a while back

```
 (define fibs
  (lambda (idx)
    ((((lambda (f)
            ((lambda (x) (x x))
             (lambda (y) (f (lambda (a)
                              (lambda (b) (((y y) a) b)))))))
       (lambda (f) (lambda (s)
                     (lambda (idx)
                       (if (= idx 0)
                           ((lambda (p)
                              (p (lambda (h) (lambda (t) h)))) s)
                           ((f (((lambda (p)
                                   (p (lambda (h) (lambda (t) t)))) s)))
                            (- idx 1)))))))
      ((((lambda (f)
            ((lambda (x) (x x))
             (lambda (y) (f (lambda (a)
                              (lambda (b) (((y y) a) b)))))))
         (lambda (f) 
           (lambda (a)
             (lambda (b)
               (((lambda (h)
                   (lambda (t) (lambda (a) ((a h) t)))) a)
                (lambda () ((f b) (+ a b)))))))) 0) 1))
     idx)))
```

It defines all of the fibonacci numbers (via a infinite list of church pairs, of course)

I did go even further, getting rid of if, 0, 1, +, and -, but in the end those were needed to convert back and forth from church numerals anyway.  And it was getting ridiculous at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I first wrote the solution in the untyped lambda calculus, using top-level definitions for things like *zero?*, *true*, *false*, etc, defined using Church encodings. This implementation assumes that multi-argument functions are curried and that functions are partially applied (like Haskell).

Church encoding natural numbers looks like:

```
(define 0  λf x. x)
(define 1  λf x. f x)
(define 2  λf x. f (f x))
(define 3  λf x. f (f (f x)))
```

Church booleans `true` and `false` are defined below

```
(define const  λx y. x)
(define U      λf. f f)
(define true   λt f. t)
(define false  λt f. f)
(define succ   λn f x. f (n f x))
(define 0      λf x. x)
(define *      λm n f x. m (n f) x)
(define zero?  λn. n (const false) true)
(define pred   λn f x. n (λg h. h (g f)) (const x) id)
```

With those pre-requisites defined, now we define the factorial function using self-application for recursion. This definition is tail-recursive.

```
(define !
  U (lambda loop acc n.
      zero? n -- branches wrapped in lambdas
              -- to accomodate call-by-value
       (lambda _. acc)
       (lambda _. (loop loop (* n acc) (pred n))))
       n) -- dummy argument to evaluate selected branch
    1)
```

From here, I cheated and performed normal order evaluation on `!`; this is essentially partial evaluation. For this to work, I had to remove the definition of `U` to prevent divergence, then add it back in after.

Here's the resulting term. It is fairly cryptic (though I would've had difficulty writing anything this short by hand, without an interpreter) so I've added comments identifying the parts I can still recognize.

```
(λx. x x)             -- self application
(λloop acc n.
  n (λy t f. f)       -- const false
    (λt f. t)         -- true
    (λ_. acc)         -- zero? branch
    (λ_. loop loop    -- other branch
      (λf. n (acc f))
      (λf x. n (λg h. h (g f)) (λy. x) (λx. x)))  -- pred
    n)  -- dummy argument
(λf. f) -- 1
```

The multiplication might be hard to spot, but it's there. Now, to test it I evaluated the term applied to 3, or `(λf x. f (f (f x)))`. Hybrid applicative and hybrid normal evaluation both reduce to a normal term without diverging, yielding `λf x. f (f (f (f (f (f x)))))`, or 6. Other reduction strategies either diverge (due to the self application) or don't reduce to normal form.